# Swift: How to reorder and omit parameters in functions stored in variables

Tags: swift, function, parameters, parameter-passing, optional-parameters

I am somewhat familiar with storing and passing around functions in Swift, however I have a few specific questions on the behavior of the language in this regard.

Say we have a variable function MathOperation:

```
var mathOperation: (Double, Double) -> Double
```

Now suppose we are setting this to the function Subtract:

```
func subtract (minuend: Double, subtrahend: Double) -> Double {
    return minuend - subtrahend
}
mathOperation = subtract
```

We should then be able to call `subtract` with

```
let result = mathOperation(3, 4.222)
```

But what if we want to pass in a function that has more parameters, or differently ordered parameters than the declaration of `mathOperation` calls for? For instance:

```
func divide (dividend: Double, divisor: Double, roundToInt: Bool = false) -> Double { ... }
```

How can I set `mathOperation` to `divide` in such a manner that `roundToInt` is ignored?

Also, is it possible to re-order the arguments? Say we have an exponentiation function in a library where it cannot be modified:

```
func exponentiate (power: Double, base: Double) -> Double { ... }
```

It is unusual to have the power before the base, and let's say that where `mathOperation` is used, we need to call it as though it were declared with `(base: Double, power: Double)`.

Is there a way to set `mathOperation` to `exponentiate` so that the parameters are reversed when it is called?

One final question. Let us say we have an interpolation function that we want to set `mathOperation` to:

```
func interpolate (start: Double, end: Double, by: Double, nonlinearity: (Double) -> Double) -> Double { ... }
```

Is there a way to set `mathOperation` to `interpolate` so that

```
mathOperation (a, b)
```

results in

```
interpolate (start: a, end: b, by: 0.5, nonlinearity: { $0 })
```

If any of these are possible, it would be ideal if someone could direct me to the official documentation where this is explained.

Comment: Short answer: It is not possible. The only alternative is to work with closures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your interpolate case (the other cases follow) just define the following:

```
mathOperation = { interpolate (start: $0, end: $1, by: 0.5, nonlinearity: { $0 })}
```

Essentially you wrap `interpolate` in a closure where some of the arguments are fixed, such as `by` to `0.5` in this example.  (This is referred to as '[partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application)')

You can also generalize this with something like the following:

```
func interpolateToMathOperation (by: Double, nonlinearity: @escaping (Double) -> Double) -> (Double, Double) -> Double {
  return { interpolate (start: $0, end: $1, by: by, nonlinearity: nonlinearity)}
}
```

The above returns a `mathOperation` for `interpolate` given the default `by` and `nonlinearity` arguments.

In action:

```
  // Just add - only an example
  1> func interpolate (start: Double, end: Double, by: Double, nonlinearity: (Double) -> Double) -> Double { return start + end }

  6> func interpolateToMathOperation (by: Double, nonlinearity: @escaping (Double) -> Double) -> (Double, Double) -> Double { 
  7.   return { interpolate (start: $0, end: $1, by: by, nonlinearity: nonlinearity)} 
  8. } 
  9> var mathOperation = interpolateToMathOperation (by: 0.25, nonlinearity: { $0 })
mathOperation: (Double, Double) -> Double = 0x00000001005ea670 $__lldb_expr15`partial apply forwarder for __lldb_expr_14.(interpolateToMathOperation (by : Swift.Double, nonlinearity : (Swift.Double) -> Swift.Double) -> (Swift.Double, Swift.Double) -> Swift.Double).(closure #1) at repl14.swift

 10> mathOperation(1,2)
$R1: Double = 3
```